# Can you make api calls in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: api, post, get, unreal-engine5

Is it somehow possible to make api calls like get/post/put/patch...?
Or can you install plugins like VaRest for UE5?

Answer (score 1):

The [VARest](https://github.com/ufna/VaRest) plugin is available for UE5 from the Epic Games Marketplace and through GitHub, and can be used in the manner you describe.